# IIS authentication is randomly getting disabled

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication, server, iis-6

This application needs both anonymous and windows authentication to be enabled.
Randomly, iis is disabling both windows and anonymous authentication. And we can to keep enabling it back again.
What could cause it iis to disable authentication?

Comment: Is the server part of some domain if yes , please check with Domain Admin if some policy restrictions are in place for Web Servers which are part of the domain.

Comment: Yes it is a part of a domain. But if there were restrictions, why is the issue observed only sometimes? Occurrence is randomly.